Cube root equation
I'm trying to solve:
$$\sqrt[3]{x^2} - \sqrt[3]{x} -6 = 0$$
I’ve tried putting the $-6$ on the other side and cubing both sides but no joy at finding value $x$.

This is a quadratic function of $\sqrt[3]x$. Maybe you can factor it or substitute $y=\sqrt[3]x$.

You really should try adding what you've done previously on this to your post. And please add more details? Last thing you want is for your first question to end up closed.

Given equation: $$\sqrt[3]{x^2} - \sqrt[3]{x} - 6 = 0$$
First, let's substitute $\sqrt[3]{x}$ with $a$, that would make $\sqrt[3]{x^2} = a^2$.
Now we can rewrite the original equation as:$${a^2} - {a} - 6 = 0$$
We can plug that into the quadratic formula as such:
$$a = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 24}}{2}$$
Which leaves us with two possible values for a:
$$a_1 = \frac{1 + 5}{2} = 3$$ $$a_2 = \frac{1 - 5}{2} = -2$$
Remembering that $a=\sqrt[3]{x}$, to get $x$ we can simply cube $a$:
$$x = a_1^3, a_2^3$$
$$x = (-2)^3, 3^3$$
Leaving us with our final x-values of:
$$x = -8, 27$$

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

I don't see why my answer is problematic. I was trying to help the author of the post understand that they needed to substitute variables instead of the way they were trying to manipulate the equation. Yes it was a poorly asked question but I still see this as possibly a valuable explanation.

Welcome to MSE. There is nothing problematic about your answer, per se, but rather the fact that the question is poorly asked. The site's rules dictate that these questions should not be answered.

Genuine question, what if I fix the original question via an edit? I don't think the idea behind the question was in bad taste, only the wording and formatting was poor. I've seen much more simple questions do well on here. The author also provided their attempt at solving to an extent by re-arranging the equation, which I think is good.

That's generally not encouraged. I would suggest you ask it as a new question following the site's rules

Wait why is it not encouraged I though that was the purpose in editing?

That's the OP's job. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/guidelines-for-context-edits-and-rewrites

@Jose Avilez I agree with æ æ on this. I think the question and this answer are very valuable to the site because they show how substitution can make an initially complicated-looking problem much more manageable.

@Jose Avilez I hate to keep extending the comments, but those guidelines support my edit entirely. I added/fixed MathJax and clarified the author's English, which are the first two things stated in that article. I also did not add an attempt nor did I change the question fundamentally. This all feels overly petty for what could be a simple, question-fix + elaborated answer.

@ææ No worries, happy to have this discussion. I think with the edits it's still a bit light on context and may be closed by the community. It will also eventually delete your answer, as questions which are closed and have negative votes get eventually deleted automatically from the site. That's why I recommend asking this as a new question with proper context and displaying an attempt.
Of course, everything I say is my own interpretation of the guidelines. You may ask in meta or in the chat if you want to get input from the mods

The basis for my opinion is the following point from the linked post: "Most questions do not need to be saved."

Just to thank you all for the answer and comments. I will now always think of substitution as a potential operation. Valuable lesson learnt. I will also try to format my future questions properly.
